# Prepend new data to UICollectionView while maintaining current scroll position without CollectionViewCell flickering

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

## Setup

I have a collectionView setup in such a way that  when user scroll up to top more data will be prepended and when user scroll to bottom more data will be appended

## Wanted Result

1. When the user scrolls to top, I want to prepend new data on top while maintaining the current scroll position of `CollectionViewCell` without any flickering.
2. When the user scrolls to the bottom, append new data while maintaining the current scroll position of `CollectionViewCell` without any flickering.

## Current Implementation

When new data is prepended as user scrolls to top, the current scroll position is not being maintained by default. so in order to maintain the scroll position. I use this simple trick as shown in the below code.

```swift
    func prepend () {
            let newData = getPrependData()
            dataSource.insert(newData, at: 0)

            let bottomOffset: CGFloat = collectionView.contentSize.height - collectionView.contentOffset.y
            CATransaction.begin()
            CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
            collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
                self.collectionView.insertSections(IndexSet(arrayLiteral: 0 ) )
            }) { finished in
                self.collectionView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.collectionView.contentSize.height - bottomOffset)
                CATransaction.commit()
            }
        }
```

The above prepend method is call base on the condition of the `scrollView.contentOffset.y` inside `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` so no animation take place when the `prepend` method is being called.

```swift
override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 800 {
                    prependVertical()
                }
        }
```

> More info on `collectionView`, The `CollectionViewCell` size is the Size of `ViewController`, which means each `Cell` take the whole screen, and `isPagingEnabled` set to `true`

## Problem

Using the above code I manage to maintain the scroll position of the `collectionView`. but the problem is `CollectionViewCell` flicker. 
I don't have to the same problem while appending new data when the user scrolls to the bottom

Comment: Without seeing more of your code or understanding more of your actual setup, it will be a bit hard to fully help solve the flickering issue.  In theory for what you are trying to achieve you shouldn't need to involve CoreAnimation at all; certainly not with `animated: false`.  Can you provide more details about your collection view? Are you using a custom UICollectionViewLayout ?  Are you using prefetching? Are you attempting to update your contentOffset while the view is still animating or are you waiting for it to pause? etc..

Comment: 1. No, I am not using custom UICollectionViewLayout, just the default one, 
2. I am not using the prefetching method
3. The prepend method is called base on the condition of the `scrollView.contentOffset.y` inside `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` so no animation takes place when the prepend method is being called. (Code update above)

if I do not involve CoreAnimation, I clearly see the movement of the cell when the new section is inserted on top. kindly guide me @ekscrypto

Comment: @ekscrypto I have added few more details too

Comment: By using "CoreAnimation" I meant that you are using CATransaction, unless I'm mistaken this is a CoreAnimation library function.

Comment: @ekscrypto is there any other way to solve this problem? My plan is to create a calendar like how apple did it, which has infinite scrolling in both direction vertically without any lag. when I append it works fine, the problem is prepend.

Comment: I would recommend to implement your own UICollectionViewLayout, and manage yourself which cell gets positioned where and when relative to the UICollectionView offset; I would use a data manager to retrieve and cache the results, and have the individual cells refresh their internal content with some fade-in animation whenever their content arrives from the network request (or some other async data load).

Comment: @ekscrypto sounds really complicated. I will research more on it, do you have any guide or tutorial on that ?

Comment: https://itnext.io/infinite-grid-using-uicollectionview-155801e4f7f4